# How fast the lifecycle of a lithium ion battery will decay in case of outdoor application?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I want to use a lithium-Ion rechargeable battery for outdoor applications. The ambient temperature would be 2 degrees Celsius (minimum) to 50 degrees celsius. As far as I know, Li-Ion battery performance degrades with temperature, but I don't know the exact rate. Does the outdoor device use rechargeable batteries like this? It may not be under direct sunlight, but a casing above it may not help that much.

Comment: How much spare energy have you got so that it might raise its own temperature a tad. I'm thinking a good thermal lagging might be pretty useful here and keep it maybe 5 or 10 degC warmer through the night.

Comment: This might make interesting reading especially the sodium-ion battery: [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-ion_battery#Advantages_and_disadvantages_over_other_battery_technologies)

Comment: Didn't know about sodium batteries. Checking the wiki link.

Comment: I just a heard a report about them on the local news channel actually while I was reading this question!!

Comment: According to the wiki, it's safe to use and the operating temperature is higher than Li-Ion. The charging cycle may not be a great issue. But the availability is very poor. There are just two shops in Alibaba selling this battery.

Comment: Try reading the manufacturer's data sheet, it will give you the information you need. If you operate out of those specs all guarantees are off.

Comment: Which battery are you looking at using and what is the maximum expected current draw?